# How to create a PDF file using functions of Graphics2D in iText 7?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

Hi~ I'm trying to migrate the source code using iText 5 to iText 7, but I have a problem.

When using iText5, I created a instance of PdfGraphics2D via createGraphicsShapes() and then drawn the objects using the APIs of Graphics2D.

But iText 7 does not provide createGraphicsShapes(), so I need help.

Of course, I found that I could drawn the objects using PdfCanvas instead of PdfGraphics2D.

But if possible, I would like to reuse the source code that uses the APIs of Graphics2D without modification (because that code is common code used in other features).

Is there a good alternative?

```
AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform();
t.scale(PDF_API_SCALE, PDF_API_SCALE);
t.translate(100, 100);

Rectangle pageRect = writer.getPageSize();
PdfGraphics2D g2d = (PdfGraphics2D)contentByte.createGraphicsShapes(pageRect.getWidth(), pageRect.getHeight());
g2d.transform(t);


// the code that needs to reuse - start
g2d.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
g2d.drawString(str, x, y);
...
// the code that needs to reuse - end

g2d.dispose();
```

Comment: If you need a PDFGraphics2D class you could consider OrsonPDF: https://github.com/jfree/orsonpdf

Comment: David, thanks for your advice. But I have to use iText 7 for Khmer language support.

Comment: PdfGraphics2D implementation was removed from iText 7 because of a considerable amount of problems with the resultant PDFs created in that way.